# font gets more bold when online on 13.3 inch mac

Tags: html, css

My website has a [My Website](http://www.vouzalis.com) bold font when I look at my macbook 13.3 inch. On desktop, mobile, ipad etc everything is looking fine. I do not have any grunt running, the screen is not zoomed in.

Does anybody have an idea what that could be? I am totally lost on this one.

**Bold Font on Mac:**
[image: Bold font on 13.3 inch]

**Normal font Desktop:**
[image: Normal font]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, but rather about fonts and/or specific OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the two screenshots use different fonts for their titles.

You have a "blocked" icon in the location bar of the top one, "This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources". Presumably the settings of the top browser (or maybe even the firewall settings on the computer) prevent the *Source Sans Pro* font from being loaded.
Once you have that solved, the same font will be used on all computers and the website will look the same.